# How are public key fingerprints generated?

Tags: encryption, ssh, cryptography

What information other than the public key itself goes into generating a fingerprint of the public key?

I re-assigned a floating IP address to a different virtual machine in possession of the same public key, and it produces a different public key fingerprint to the previous virtual machine.

So I assume that the public key isn't the sole input in generating a key fingerprint?

Comment: Strange: that should mean the pulbic key itself has changed. ssh-keyscan produces two different keys? (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408349/7490)